# PERL CGI: How to fix split function with reading/displaying data on a table?

Tags: perl, cgi

The items in the text file are separated with a pipe symbol "|". The CGI file below will display the items in a table under their designated labels. Please see this [Table Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6UZH.png), that's what I have. How do I fix so the items are in their designated columns and not just in one? There's no MySQL or SQL to hold the data, just a text file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use strict;
use warnings;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

 print "<TABLE BORDER>\n";
 print "<TR><TH>SKU Code<TH>Name<TH>Description<TH>Price"; 

open ( ORDERS, "inventory.txt" ) or die "Error opening file, $!";
 while(<ORDERS>) {
    print "<TR>\n";
    print "<TD>";
my @fields=split(/\<\*\>/);
    print join(`<TD>`,@fields); 
    print "</TR>";
 }
close ORDERS;
 print "</TABLE>";
```

Here is the CGI File that was used to store the items to the text file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
my $sku = param('sku_code');
my $cust = param('customer');
my $description = param('description');
my $selling = param('price');
my $price = sprintf("\$%.2f");

print <<HERE;
<HTML>
<BODY>
<H3>Here is your order...please check</H3>
SKU: $sku<br>
Name: $cust<br>
Description: $description<br>
Selling Price: $price<br>
HERE
open (ORDERS, ">>inventory.txt") or die "File error, $!";

print ORDERS "$sku|$cust|$description|$price\n";
close ORDERS;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will work.

```
# Best practice: three-arg open() and lexical filehandle
open my $order_fh, '<', 'inventory.txt' or die "Error opening file, $!";

while(<$order_fh>) {
  print "<TR>\n";
  print '<TD>' . join('</TD><TD>', split /\|/) . "</TD>\n";
  print "</TR>\n";
}

close $order_fh;
```

This code looks [rather familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347629/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-by-putting-its-data-in-a-table-using-cgi-in-perl/40356954#40356954). Please consider the advice I gave there about using a templating system.

Some other comments on your code:

- `use warnings` replaces `-w`. You don't need both.
- Use `header()` (from CGI.pm) to print the header.
- `my $price = sprintf("\$%.2f")` - this looks wrong!
- You really need to add some file locking.
- Your HTML looks like it's from 1995. We tend to close elements these days.

Answer (score 0):

to split each line in ORDERS by pipe characters you should say:

```
my @fields=split(/\|/, $_);
```

Comment: The table doesn't seem to have any changes.

Comment: sorry,  copy-paste to format it well ate the backslash